# Unable to copy a .png(image) file in the system in c++ can anyone help me how to do this?

Tags: image-processing, c++17, binaryfiles, file-handling

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
using namespace std;
main()
{
ifstream a1;
ofstream o1;
a1.open("fail.png",ios::binary);
o1.open("fail2.png",ios::binary);
long long int t;
t=a1.get();
while(!a1.eof())
{
//  cout<<t<<" ";
    o1<<t;
    t=a1.get();
}
a1.close();
o1.close();
}
```

this is my code can anyone help me what should i do wrong in my code and please dont say that i have to use windows.h in my program because i want to execute my code in only pure file handling method if anyone know the answer then please help me with the proper code :(

Comment: `istream::get()` returns an `int`, which you cast to some other type and write out. You read 4 bytes and write 8.

Comment: You use C++17, you should use `std::filesystem::copy_file`.